# Opening a file containing unicode characters using notepad++ appears corrupted

Tags: unicode, notepad++

I'm using the latest version of Notepad ++ 6.3.1 and using a windows os. While trying to open a file containing unicode character appears corrupted despite changing the encoding to UTP8. It is displayed like "[][][][]". I'm I missing something in the settings? Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: I think the settings will depend on the flavor of unicode -- is it little endian, big endian, with or without bom, UTF-16, UTF-8, UTF-32?  Can you give us any more information about the file, or a link to a representative example?

Comment: I'm trying to open a file that has Japanese characters in it. And I've set the encoding to UTF-8. The same file looks good in a different machine for notepad and the settings also seems similar. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You are probably missing a font that is capable of rendering Japanese glyphs.  So you'll get a rectangle instead.  Google "xp asian fonts" for a possible fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is a font issue. You need a font containing the Japanese characters as installed in your computer, and you also need to have Notepad++ set to use such a font, for the kind of text being viewed. But it seems that Notepad++ is capable of using fallback fonts when needed (e.g., when the font selected does not contain all characters appearing in the text), so the problem is probably that *no* font in your system contains the characters. See e.g. the list [East Asian Unicode fonts for Windows computers](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts-east-asian.html).

Comment: Not necessarily a font issue. My answer shows that Notepad++ switches between 'proper' character display and 'block' display for the SAME character, depending on line-breaks (and un-line-breaks)

Answer (score 0):

Not a font issue, unfortunately. Try with these characters, with UTF-16 encoding:
, ,  (> U+FFFF)

Conclusion: Notepad++ doesn't have full Unicode support (unlike Windows Notepad or AkelPad)

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is also inconsistent. With a document in UTF-8, using Lucida Console font, create a line

⇐⇑⇒⇓⇔⇕⇖⇗⇘⇙

and enter a newline in the middle - second line becomes 5 blocks, and then delete newline - all 10 characters display properly.

With font MS Gothic, this test always displays proper characters

> Notepad++ v7.5.1   (64-bit)
>   Build time : Aug 29 2017 - 02:38:44
>   Path : C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
>   Admin mode : OFF
>   Local Conf mode : OFF
>   OS : Windows 10 (64-bit)
>   Plugins : mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll